# Should I Write a Plugin For This? Changing Turtlebot wheel diameter after model loads

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I need to change the diameter of the Turtlebot's wheels within a Gazebo simulation.  I've found the xacro file in which the wheel diameter is getting set (below).

I'm wondering if writing a plugin to change the wheel diameter is appropriate.  My other idea is to make a second Turtlebot URDF with the new wheel diameter, delete the original Turtlebot model from the Gazebo world, and spawn the new one in its place.

Here's where wheel_diameter is set:

```
    <plugin name="kobuki_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_kobuki.so"> 
     <publish_tf>1</publish_tf> 
                       
      <wheel_diameter>0.070</wheel_diameter> 

                                        
           </plugin> 
  </gazebo>
```

Link to the whole file:
https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/blob/a540661bbd6c11ba8c9a6482251562f9b62970c2/kobuki_description/urdf/kobuki_gazebo.urdf.xacro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14475/should-i-write-a-plugin-for-this?-changing-turtlebot-wheel-diameter-after-model-loads./) by [ElizabethA](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2837/elizabetha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What's wrong with writing a second xacro? You shouldn't need to delete/respawn, however. Find the launch file that called `spawn_model`, then copy that as your own launch file and change the model to launch your modified version instead.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ElizabethA](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2837/elizabetha/) on 2016-09-27**:
I'm going to go with the second xacro.  My delete/respawn plan is because I'm going to navigate an environment up to a point with one Turtlebot, and then I'm going to switch out that model with Turtlebot model with the wheel adjustment, to simulate a tire going flat.

Thanks for your feedback!

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-09-27**:
please accept this answer so others can find it. glad you found it useful